# Windows Azure - sql database with api

Tags: sql, database, api, azure

I have SOAP services with data. I want to download all data from that service and upload it to my own server and then use these data from my server (don't worry I have permission for that). I want to do it because now I don't have function from that service which I need.

I want to use Windows Azure for this and I think SQL Database scenario would be best. Now I have classes for previous SOAP service so I think EF Code first would help me with creating database and I upload data somehow. But what about API? How can I access my data from windows phone or tablet? Is azure database enought or I must create more? Is there any good article for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure gives you a few options to expose an API to your mobile clients:

- You could build an API yourself with the ASP.NET Web API (and use SQL Azure as backend): [Mobile-friendly REST service using ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/rest-service-using-web-api/)
- You can use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), this does all the heavy lifting of building a backend for you

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are saying, is that you are aggregating data from several sources and storing the information in your own database.  And, you would like your database to be Azure Database.  Then, you want to build an API to expose the data you retrieved.

If this is indeed your goal, then yes, Azure will do everything you need.  I'd recommend checking out [Web API in conjunction with your Azure deployment](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/rest-service-using-web-api/).  I've used this scheme with some success over the past year.

**Warning:**  You should know that Azure Database does not have an SLA which means that Microsoft does not guarantee any level of performance including transactions/second.  This means that if your API has a high load, you could end up getting throttled heavily in an unpredictable way.  I've been bitten by this before and ended up moving my data to Azure Table Storage instead.

Comment: Thank you both, you've been right too I just choose second answer (I hope it doen't matter). And thanks for that SLA warning.

Comment: @Bibo no problem, I'm glad I could help. Sandrino's answer is better, you were right to pick it :)